# Unable to connect to remote rabbitmq server using pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to connect to my remote rabbitmq using pika but I am getting Connectionclosed() error. I have made the required changes in rabbit.config for guest user to allow all connections and also the same connection works from my Java code. I even tried creating a new user with all the permission and connecting it, but it still doesn't work. The same code works fine on my localhost though. Can anyone please let me know what might I be doing wrong here?

```
def queue_message(message, queue):
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('xxxx', 'xxxx')
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('remote-server',
                                   5672,
                                    '/',
                                    credentials)
   connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
   channel = connection.channel()
   channel.queue_declare(queue='python_update_queue')
   channel.basic_publish(exchange='update.fanout',
                  body=message)
   logger.info("Sent message: {} to queue: {}".format(message, queue))
   print 'message sent'
   connection.close()
```

Below is the error I get:

```
app/project/rabbitmq.py" in queue_message
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py" in __init__
     self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py" in ss_io_for_connection_setup
                        self._open_error_result.is_ready)
env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py" in _flush_output
         raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

Answer (score 5):

add a connection timeout to your connection parameters - you're probably running into a timeout issue where the connection isn't happening fast enough, across the network.

also, your code is explicitly calling `connection.close()` ... so that may be why your connection is closing

Comment: You are right about the timeout. The default timeout in pika is set to 0.25 seconds. After increasing this timeout, everything has been working smoothly. Thanks!

Comment: Gosh I was looking for hours until I found this socket timeout tips. Thanks a lot, it's finally working now...

Answer (score 4):

It was indeed a timeout issue. After increasing the timeout in the connection parameters, the connection was established properly.

```
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('remote-server',
                                   5672,
                                   '/',
                                   socket_timeout=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to remote rabbitmq server, check this:

1. remote server port open with firewall
2. remote server have public ip and rabbitmq user have access to that server
3. rabbitmq server is activately running

Answer (score -1):

- add your user admin in administrator tag;

  ```
  rabbitmqctl set_user_tags admin administrator
  ```
- add enough permissions to the user admin

  ```
  rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / admin ".*" ".*" ".*"
  ```